# Parent Window access lost in child's child window

Tags: javascript, html

In my application there is a parent window. It opens a new child window which in turn opens a new child window. During this the parent window references is lost and hence not able to access parent form elements in the child window. It is working in IE.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: function setXXX(id)
 {
  opener.window.setYYY(id);
  window.close();
 }

Comment: Check this, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29296/JavaScript-to-close-child-windows